# Simple multiplication on cuda GPU giving error

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust

I am doing the following on the GPU

```
float decPart = valAtIndex - (int)valAtIndex;
int docID = decPart * numDocs;
```

where valAtIdex if of type `float` and numDocs also of type `float`. For my case, decPart was 0.2 and numDocs was 10. However, when I print docID, it is printed as 1 (it should be 2). Can somebody please tell me where am I making a mistake?

Below is the full method if it helps

```
__global__ 
void finalNc(float* scSortedCounts, int* pos, int* maxCountEx, float numDocs, 
             int lengthStreamCompacted, int* finalNc, int actualLengthPos, 
             float* val, int* docIndex, int* acV ,int* ptwrite,int* diff,
             int* posIndex)
{ 
    int index = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; 
    if(index < lengthStreamCompacted){ 
        float valAtIndex = scSortedCounts[index]; 
        float decPart = valAtIndex - (int)valAtIndex; 
        int docID = decPart * numDocs; 
        int actualCount = (int)valAtIndex; 
        int placeToWrite = maxCountEx[docID] + actualCount; 
        if( index == (lengthStreamCompacted -1 )){ 
            finalNc[placeToWrite] = actualLengthPos - pos[index]; 
        }else{ 
            finalNc[placeToWrite] = pos[index + 1] + pos[index]; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: is `decPart` really 0.2, or might it have actually been 0.19999999999?

Comment: Where do you print docID? in the host using the docID host declaration? Or in kernel, using the docID device declaration?

Comment: @Programmer: Unless I am mistaken, it can't be *exactly* 0.2 because that value isn't exactly representable in IEEE 754 binary32 format. Depending on the rounding mode, it must be either `3E4CCCCC` (1.99999988079071044921875E-1) or `3E4CCCCD` (2.0000000298023223876953125E-1). That might explain the error.

Comment: To confirm what @talonmies commented try `__float2int_rd (float x)` in your kernel and `floor (float x )` in your host code and compare your results.

Comment: @PQB: How does converting something from float2int in the kernel help? What does it help me verify. Btw, i am printing docID in the host after copying it to a host variable

Comment: @talonmies: I think you are correct. I will be obliged if you could also suggest the solution

Comment: @Programmer: Your question asks for an explanation as to why you were not getting results you expect, and the answer seems to be that you were mistaken in the true values of inputs or intermediate values in the kernel. I had added an answer which I think demonstrates that there is nothing wrong with the actual computation. But I don't understand what "solution" you are asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the case you have mentioned, it appears that the result you are seeing is correct, and the source of your confusion is down to IEEE single precision representation of the intermediate results in your calculations (and perhaps rounding in printing or displaying of those intermediate results).

For the example you provide, a value of 0.2f is not *exactly* representable as a binary32 value. The two possible values are either

```
3E4CCCCC (1.99999988079071044921875E-1)
```

or

```
3E4CCCCD (2.0000000298023223876953125E-1)
```

If the first value was the actual value of `docID`, then the intermediate calculation you mention should produce 1 (which is what you observed). If it was second value, the result would be 2. This is absolutely expected behaviour.

To illustrate the effect of IEEE rounding modes and help put your mind at ease that there is no error here, have a look at the following example code, which performs the calculation you are asking about with one of three possible `float` to `integer` conversions - plain truncation, IEEE 754 round towards minus infinity, and IEEE 754 round towards plus infinity. I have templated the kernel and run it for each case on a set of random float values between 1 and 10. You can compile and run it for yourself and verify that the plain truncation (as in your code) really does work as intended, as well as the behaviour of the IEEE compliant "round up" and "round down" conversions on the output.

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/device_malloc.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

template<int version>
__global__
void kernel(const float *inputs, int *outputs, int numDocs, int N)
{
    int index = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; 

    if(index < N){ 
        float valAtIndex = inputs[index];
        int intPart;
        switch(version) {
            case 2:
                intPart = __float2int_ru(valAtIndex);
                break;
            case 1:
                intPart = __float2int_rd(valAtIndex);
                break;
            case 0:
            default:
                intPart = int(valAtIndex);
                break;
        }
        float decPart = valAtIndex - intPart;
        int docID = decPart * numDocs;
        outputs[index] = docID;
    }
}

inline float frand(){
    return 1.0f + 9.0f * ((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX);
}

int main(void)
{
    const size_t N = 100;
    const int numdocs = 10;

    srand(time(NULL));

    thrust::host_vector<float> values(N);
    thrust::host_vector<int> outputs(3*N);
    std::generate(values.begin(), values.end(), frand);

    thrust::device_ptr<float> in = thrust::device_malloc<float>(N);
    float * _in = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(in);
    thrust::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), in);

    thrust::device_ptr<int> out = thrust::device_malloc<int>(3*N);
    int * _out = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(out);

    kernel<0><<<1,128>>>(_in, _out, numdocs, N);
    kernel<1><<<1,128>>>(_in, _out+N, numdocs, N);
    kernel<2><<<1,128>>>(_in, _out+(2*N), numdocs, N);

    thrust::copy(out, out+3*N, outputs.begin());

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        printf("%.10f %d %d %d\n", 
                values[i], outputs[i], outputs[N+i], outputs[2*N+i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed ans! you rock dude